# How do I properly load the lit-html module in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, lit-html

I'm trying to use lit-html to save my self some time, but I'm having trouble getting everything set up correctly.

Electron 4.1.1

Node 11.15

As of 5 minutes before posting this, I've run npm install and electron-rebuild,  no luck.

I use require() as one would with any other NPM package

```
var render = require('lit-html').render
var html = require('lit-html').html
console.log(require("lit-html"))
```

Unfortunately, I'm greeted with this error[image]
In reference to the three lines of code above.

I don't see any problems with my code.

I've tried reinstalling lit-html through NPM to no avail. I would really love to use this library, but first I have to get over this hurdle. If I'm being honest, I don't know if this error is reproducible, but nothing I do seems to fix it. The problem seems to lie with node and the way that imports are handled.

Am I missing something here? Is this a common issue? If so, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Is lit-html in CJS format or ES Module?

Comment: I'm very new to lit-html, could you clarify? Based on what the errors are saying I would guess CJS (I don't know what CJS is though lol) Edit: After looking up CJS (which I'm assuming is just commonJS) I would go with that.

Comment: CJS is what Node uses, so when you're `require`ing the code it has to be in that format. If lit-html is in ES Module format `import ... from ...` and `export x` you'll need to transpile it.

Comment: That would make sense. It seems that CommonJS is what's freaking out. This would explain the errors. It seems weird that an NPM package should need to be transpiled though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You need to transpile lit-html before you can `require` it

I tested `require('lit-html')` and I was greeted with this error:

```
/path/to/project/node_modules/lit-html/lit-html.js:31
import { defaultTemplateProcessor } from './lib/default-template-processor.js';
```

It clearly states that the error is coming from `lit-html/lit-html.js:31` where the line uses ES Module `import` syntax.

You can transpile it using tools like Babel or similar ones. However, you may want to try using ES Module syntax so you can import lit-html without transpiling it.

Example:

```html
<!-- HTML File -->
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
```

```js
// index.js
import { html } from 'lit-html';
```

## What if you can't use `type="module"`

If you are unable to use the `type="module"` method above, you can also use [the ESM package](https://npm.im/esm) (possibly outdated).

> ESM is a brilliantly simple, babel-less, bundle-less ECMAScript module loader.

Here are a few examples of how to use it:

1. Using the node require flag (`-r`) to load `esm` before everything else

```bash
node -r esm index.js
```

2. Loading `esm` in your main file then loading the rest of your code.

```js
// Set options as a parameter, environment variable, or rc file.
require = require('esm')(module/*, options*/)
module.exports = require('./main.js')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You are correct that lit-html uses ES6 modules. Do you know how exactly I would go about using these modules without transpiling? Based on reading I've just done, it looks like you can in fact use these modules without any extra packages or transpiling, but .mjs files are needed rather than JS files. Does this mean I only need to change the lit-html.js file to lit-html.mjs or do I have to go through and change every file that uses an es6 import?

Comment: .mjs is not needed

Comment: The last part of my example covers switching to ES Module syntax

Comment: I've used the last part in my index.html to require the renderer.js instead of requiring it immediately and now lit-html works inside electron! Thank you very much @ChrisBrownie55